# Geometry Nodes - Vertex Group - Add Less More

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, geometry

I convert Weight Paint(Vertex group) to Shader map (with geometry nodes), And I want to select more (like ctlr + (+) in edit mode) graiden in geometr nodes, can you hepl please, thank you :)

[image: my pghoto for question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Blur Attribute** node for this. Later add a clamped multiply node (or may be a power node,map range, or even an RGB curves node if you want to have control over the falloff) so that if some values are a bit low, you can recover those. [image]

Comment: thank you very very much, thank you :)

Comment: Hey, if this this has solved your issue and is a satisfying answer, mark it as accepted to indicate others that the issue is solved.

Comment: @3DTasarımOkulu a tick is the best thanks you can leave :)